# how to control multi thread access to the object in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

i am writing server in java.
for purpose of this question lets say the following:
server can accept multiple clients, each one in its own thread.
each client once connected calls one method on the server which draws some graphic object.
only one instance of the method must be active at once. in case this method is active at the same time at multiple threads, the result will be that drawn object would be scrambled.
it takes around 100ms for method to execute.
to prevent multiple threads from accessing the method at once, i added static field of the class which once this method is called is updated to mark that method is active, and once method completes it updates the property to mark that method is inactive.
each thread calls this method, but first thing method does is check the value of that field, and if it indicates that another instance of the method is already executing, it puts this thread to sleep for short time, and once it wakes up, it periodically checks the value of the field, and once value indicates another thread is complete executing this method, then another thread continues, updates the value of this field to indicate it is executing and then executes, and again updates it to indicate it finished executing. this goes for each thread once it calls the method.

this approach improved cases where collision occurs, but it did not eliminated it completely.
this is because it takes time since some thread detects that another thread is finished executing until it updates the parameter to indicate that it is now executing again. this time is very short, less than a 1ms, but still it is possible for collision to occur, that is for more than one thread to detect that method is not executing. since it is possible that since one thread detects method is not executing until it marks it as executing that in the mean time another thread also detects this method as not executing.

i know this might seam confusing, so i prepared a small example for you to understand me better:

```
public class some_class_acessed_by_multiple_threads
{
    private static volatile java.lang.Boolean lock_access;
    static 
    {
        lock_access = false;
    }
    public static void some_method_called_by_multiple_threads() throws java.lang.InterruptedException
    {
        //detection.
        while(lock_access)
        {
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(64);
        }
        //locking access to other threads.
        lock_access =true;
        some_method_which_must_not_be_active_in_multiple_threads_at_once();
        //once execution completes, unlocking access to other threads.
        lock_access =false;
    }
    private static void some_method_which_must_not_be_active_in_multiple_threads_at_once()
    {
        //draw some object.
    }
}
```

if i use logic like in this example above to prevent access to method by more than one thread at once, it works great for small number of threads.
if 1, 2, 5, 10, 50 clients is connected, collisions not occur.

but if i have lets say 1000 clients (what means 1000 threads fighting to access this method for drawing objects) or more, collisions still start to happen very often.
as you can see from my example, from the time line "detection" finishes executing until the time line "locking access..." finishes executing, it passes some time. probably time in microseconds, but still some time passes.

so my question to you is, do you have any suggestions on how i can improve my code above, so that not even 1000 threads fighting for access to the method for drawing objects can cause collision?

thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You can use `synchronized` or `Lock`

Comment: Side note: please follow the widespread coding conventions in Java : underscore is **only** for constants, and class names start upper case.

Comment: The other that is really strange: you have some advanced problem here, but your design is using static calls all over the place?!

Comment: You seem to reinvent the wheel. Java is known with its great multithreading support.

Comment: @GhostCat That's one way to create a singleton I guess... Not a pretty one and there shouldn't even be need for one really.

Comment: GhostCat, it is more readable if i use "method_name" than "methodName".
and what is wrong with static?

Comment: For 99% of experienced Java programmers yes methodName is more readable because that is what we are used to see! And static is an abnormality in good OO design, to be used carefully, not indiscriminately! As it leads to tight coupling of your classes and can make unit testing much harder.

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for a `ReadWriteLock`.

Comment: but ghostcat, in my example this has to be static. i have to make "lock_access" static, because if it is not static, it will not be common to all objects using it. one thread can make one object of "some_class_acessed_by_multiple_threads", and other thread can make another object of this class, and if "lock_access" is not static, changes to one object will not be visible in other object. so in that case "lock_access" is not useful, since the purpose of the "lock_access" is to make its value available globally, for all threads. it simply can not be dynamic, it must be static.

Comment: and about the method. well there is only one method "some_method_called_by_multiple_threads", and this method does the same each time it is called. then why should this method be dynamic? why should i allow multiple objects of this class to exist, if each invocation of the method does exactly the same thing no matter on which object it is called?
it is illogical, because if method is dynamic, it means i have to create object of that class in order to use it. so if i allow objects to be created, then i can create 100 objects, where if i call this method on any of them, the result would be same

Comment: so, therefore, what is the point of having this method dynamic?
dynamic methods should be used when their result is dependent upon some parameter of the object. if invocation always has the same result, then it is illogical to allow objects to exist so that each object can have its own method which does the same thing. it is waste of memory. This method should be static.

Comment: @SYOBSYOT Sorry, but it sounds like you don't have much plan of what you are talking about. There are **many** options to solve such kind of problems, and **static** may be the first one that comes to mind, but as said: it has **severe** drawbacks. And you know, java is an OO language; but you are using it like a imperative one. All I am saying is: if you are serious about working with an OO language; then you should really look into such topics. For example: the advantage of dynamic objects is polymorphism. What happens when you have to enhance your server; and **different** actions

Comment: @SYOBSYOT will be required. **static** works nicely for the **first** phases of a project, but then, sooner or later, you run into its limitations. Because all of a sudden it turns out to make enhancements really complicated if everything is tightly sewed together; and always doing using static. No chances to use interfaces, no polymorphism, nothing. And well, seriously: you didn't know about the **synchronized** keyword. But that is Java 101 super basic stuff. So, how sure are you that your knowledge of "static is just great here" isn't on the same level of naivety?!

Comment: @SYOBSYOT Besides: I seem to be focused that your one static method has to do that "drawing" work. Why is that? I could envision a solution where your incoming requests simply push "commands" into some kind of queue; and that a **single** thread has the job of taking jobs from that queue and do the real work. Then your other threads no syncing at all; you only need a reasonable (probably complex) "queue" thing in the middle.

Comment: well, this is just an example. i am not using these methods from this example in my real project. and i think it is now too late for me to start changing static stuff to dynamic stuff, because my real server project already has 50000 lines of code, so, too late for changes now. it is not like i always use static methods. i have about 800 methods in my project and the ration is about 60:40 for dynamic methods. so only 40% of methods in my project are static. but still, too much for me to redesign them now. i will continue with my project without changes.

Comment: about polymorphism, i use it when required, and in my case only about 10% of classes extend some other class. but i am not unfamiliar with that concept. about interfaces, they are mostly just waste of time.                      they do not do anything, just declare some methods. methods which does not have to be declared at all. it is also illogical for me to use them..in same extremely rare cases (like in 0.1% of cases) i used them, but mostly they are just waste of time. i could be spending time writing code which actually does something, and to spend it on writing interfaces - illogical.

Comment: well, i do not know, so that is why i asked here. i never needed synchronized keyword before. and it is not most basic stuff. most basic stuff is how  to write "main" method, how to print something in the console,  how to read some numbers from the user, and perform some calculations and such stuff. this is most  basic.  synchronized is several levels after.
yea, "some_method_which_must_not_be_active_in_multiple_threads_at_once" in my example is supposed to draw something in the console.
not important for my example. but in my real project, the problem is in graphic user interface i am...

Comment: ...working on. interface consists of several classes defining different gui objects, and at once only one graphic object should be updated. so i use this technique with static lock variable in super class (base class of all graphic objects). and each object once enters method for updating, locks the whole gui so that no other objects can be updated at that time, until it finishes. and i said draw, because the updating in my project is done by "draw" method, which redraws some object. and that draw method is not actually static, it is dynamic.in the matter of fact, my graphic user interface...

Comment: ...has 30000 lines of code, and only methods which are static in the whole graphic user interface are lock, unlock and is locked methods. (those are not the names, but ok). everything else is dynamic. at least in lover level classes. higher classes which define how windows look, are static, but not important.
yeap, i know the thing with queue, which i have hard time spelling, so  i just call it stack. i am not usually using this approach, but it is possible i will be using once. but in my real project, i do not think this would be applicable on my graphic user interface.

Comment: and by the way, it is hard to keep track about all features of all languages. i was writing programs in many languages, not just java. i even wrote some in assembly language. not complex one, but still. i was also writing programs in c, in c++, in java, in basic, in cmd, in powershell, in net framework, in labview, in ladder, matlab and i think this is it. or i missed one. i think i missed one, but ok, it is probably not important since i can not remember it. anyway, it is hard to keep track of all features in all languages. i mostly write programs in powershell and cmd. c and java sometimes.

Comment: plus, i  was not working ever in a development team of some company. 98% of programs i write, i write for myself, and sometimes for my friends. the other 2% i write for my school. so, i am not so familiar with such stuff, such as conventions. for me "method_name" is much better than "methodName", and it will be probably for several years in the future, until i get a job and some experience in professional development team.

 if "word1Word2" is more readable than "word1_word2", theniwillbewritinglikethistoallyourposts,soyoucanreaditmoreeasyly.formethisisextrahardtoread, and this (or_even_this

Comment: ) is much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the built-in `synchronized` java keyword?

```
private static void some_method_which_must_not_be_active_in_multiple_threads_at_once()
```

becomes

```
private static synchronized void some_method_which_must_not_be_active_in_multiple_threads_at_once()
```

This way, each thread has to kave a token to run this method. Tell us if it helps!

Comment: no i have not used synchronized keyword until now.
it seams that it is working great.

thank you!
♥ ♥ ♥

Answer (score 1):

you should use synchronization...
simply synchronize the method

```
public static synchronized void some_method_called_by_multiple_threads() throws java.lang.InterruptedException
```

synchronization simply means one thread can access the method at a time. refer the API documentations for more details